# How to design a table with transparent borders and spacing with background

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

what css values do I need for table css in order to look like this:
[image]

I've wasted over 12 hours trying to figure it out.
I wouldn't ask a stupid question like this if I wasn't giving up.

Comment: *with background* - To the table or the page or the gray cell background?

Comment: Please provide the code you have come up with so far, highlighting what has been causing problems for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the background below the table is white then you may try something like this

```
table, table tr, table td {
  border : 1px solid white;
}
```

If this does not work then please post a jsfiddle..

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the help of border-collapse property.

```css
body
{
  background: #345;
}
table
{
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  border: 0;
  margin: 1em;
}
td
{
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 5px;
}



tr:nth-child(odd) td
{
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
tr:nth-child(even) td
{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set `padding`for spacing around cells and `background-color` for your table `td`.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xoaf9Lc6/)