# Bootstrap 4 tables with transparent border

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make the border between rows transparent so the color of the page background shows through.

The borders come from td, and the background color comes from the tr, so if I make the td border transparent, the background of the tr shows through.  I've tried removing th td border and using just a tr border, but I can't seem to get the border to appear.

Consider the following table, using the standard bootstrap 4.2 css:

```
<div style="background-color:white">
    <table class="table table-gap table-striped table-striped-alt">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>A</td><td>B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>C</td><td>D</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>E</td><td>F</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I've added my own css.  This colors the odd rows, where the standard boostrap table-striped colors even rows.  It also attempts to display a transparent border on both the tr and the th/td, which does not work:

```
<style type="text/css">   
    /*Color the alternating rows that table-striped does not
    .table-striped-alt tr:not(:nth-of-type(odd))
    {
        background-color: #007bff !important;
    } 

    .table-gap tr > *
    {
        border-top: 3px solid transparent !important;
    }
    .table-gap tr
    {
        border-top: 3px solid transparent !important;
    }
</style>
```

[image]

So I tried changing the tr borders to yellow and the td/th to red just to see if that had any affect.  The td/th displayed the border, but the tr did not display a border, and the td did:

```
<style type="text/css">    
    .table-striped-alt tr:not(:nth-of-type(odd))
    {
        background-color: #007bff !important;
    }
    .table-gap tr > *
    {
        border-top: 3px solid red !important;
    }
    .table-gap tr
    {
        border-top:3px solid yellow !important
    }
</style>
```

[image]

So I played with the border-collapse, and set it to 'separate', which still did not display a border on the tr.  It actually had a transparent spacing around all cells.  It wasn't desirable because I only wanted the transparent spacing above and below cells.

```
<style type="text/css">    
    .table-striped-alt tr:not(:nth-of-type(odd))
    {
        background-color: #007bff !important;
    }
    .table-gap tr > *
    {
        border-top: 3px solid red !important;
    }
    .table-gap tr
    {
        border-top:3px solid yellow !important
    }

    table
    {
     border-collapse:separate;
    }
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to design a table with transparent borders and spacing with background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482901/how-to-design-a-table-with-transparent-borders-and-spacing-with-background)

Answer (score 2):

Table borders can be tricky. Instead, just space the cells.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate; /* boom */
  border-spacing: 0 5px; /* bam */
}

.table td {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}

.table-striped-alt tr:not(:nth-of-type(odd)) {
  background-color: #007bff !important;
}

.table-gap tr>* {
  border-top: 3px solid red !important;
}

.table-gap tr {
  border-top: 3px solid yellow !important
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div>
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>F</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: oh, border-spacing to eliminate the space between cells on the same row, great!. This works great for most of my cases.   Is it possible to turn off the border spacing on some rows?  I have some instances where I have multi-line rows, so I have multiple tbody elements which act as the visual row, and each tbody element might have more than one tr so I can get a multiline "row".  in this instance,  I want the space between the tbody elements.

Comment: You can select rows by index or by adding a class to the spacer rows, among other techniques. You should open a new question for that.